# attaching rows together if they share same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of patients where a patient can have zero or as many diagnoses as a patient has.

My goal is to show a list of all the patients with all their  diagnoses with only one row for each patient and their diagnoses.

Due to the database structure by the former developers when I make the needed SQL query I get a row for each diagnoses the patient has.
Example of a patient who has 2 diagnoses: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g28Am.png)

My question is if there is a way those two diagnoses would be on the same row as they both have the same id. So my list of all patients only contains one row pr. patient.

I tagged PHP as well as MYSQL as I'm outputting the data in PHP, I thought maybe it could be done in PHP if it can't in SQL?

This is the query I used to showcase a patient with two diagnoses. I use the same query for showing all patients just with some a few more columns selected and without the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT `DK Diagnoses`.`No`,`DK Diagnoses`.`EMGDiagText`
FROM `DK Diagnoses`
JOIN `PATIENTINFO` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `SEXCODE` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Sex` = `SEXCODE`.`SexCode`
JOIN `PROBABILITYCODE` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`Prob` = `PROBABILITYCODE`.`Code`
JOIN `EXAMINFO` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam` = `EXAMINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `REFTYPE` ON `EXAMINFO`.`RefSource` = `REFTYPE`.`Refsource`
WHERE `DK Diagnoses`.`LabCode` = "Gold" AND  `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = 2598
ORDER BY `DK Diagnoses`.`No` DESC
```

Comment: To be honest, I think you'd be better off with the current structure and use a loop to process the rows in PHP

Comment: I'm using a loop to process the rows, so are you suggesting you can via PHP get all diagnoses for each patient on one row? 

Right now through my PHP loop, I'm getting pretty much the same output as from my SQL example..

Comment: I don't think you actually want them all in one row. The data should remain structured - it looks like your DB structure is good (a patient has many diagnoses). You can use PHP to format the results into a single table row if you want to by looping and creating multiple table cells in a single `<tr>` element

Comment: @Fred Well you need to add logic and some sort of tracking mechanism which lets you know how big of a `rowspan` to apply to the first `<td>` (patient No.)

Comment: why do you want them in one row? What if they have 20 diagnoses? That will be unreadable. IMHO it's a better UX to display them in separate rows, just like they're stored in the database. If it takes up a lot of space you could use some JS to show/hide it at the user's request.

Comment: You want something like https://jsfiddle.net/sgc0ky3b/ ?

Comment: Thank you. That make sense. What would you call this particular approach so I can try to research more about it or can you suggest somewhere I can read more about this approach? I do understand the principle but due to my PHP skills/experience I have to see/read more about it to execute it.

This comment was meant for Robbie, sorry before finishing this comment the other comments were made..

Comment: Yes MonkeyZeus, that looks perfect.

Comment: I think including spaces (' ') in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Fred Nice, now that you have an idea of the HTML you need, feel free to try something out and if you get stuck then come back.

Comment: As you suggest, seriously consider handling issues of data display such as this in application code.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sounds good, I will try to figure out how to create the logic in my PHP I need.

Comment: Sounds good. Keep in mind what @ADyson mentioned about showing too much data at once because you could quickly overwhelm your users with too much information. Consider this updated example https://jsfiddle.net/sgc0ky3b/1/ but for the love of web development do not use `onclick=""` like my quick n' dirty example shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `GROUP_CONCAT`. It will merge all multiple records from `DK Diagnoses` table with same `NO` into one row with a specific separator like this:

```
SELECT `DK Diagnoses`.`No`, GROUP_CONCAT(`DK Diagnoses`.`EMGDiagText` separator '-[!$!]-') AS `EMGDiagText`
FROM `DK Diagnoses`
JOIN `PATIENTINFO` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `SEXCODE` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Sex` = `SEXCODE`.`SexCode`
JOIN `PROBABILITYCODE` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`Prob` = `PROBABILITYCODE`.`Code`
JOIN `EXAMINFO` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam` = `EXAMINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `REFTYPE` ON `EXAMINFO`.`RefSource` = `REFTYPE`.`Refsource`
WHERE `DK Diagnoses`.`LabCode` = "Gold" AND  `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = 2598
GROUP BY `DK Diagnoses`.`No`
ORDER BY `DK Diagnoses`.`No` DESC
```

Here my key to merge multiple records into one is `-[!$!]-`. So now, you will get the same number of records as compared to the total unique patient but their multiple diagnoses will be grouped into one long string contacted by  `-[!$!]-` key.

You can loop over the records to print all unique patients and at the time of printing `EMGDiagText` just `explode()` by specified key and loop over it again. e.g.

```
foreach($result as $row){
    echo '<tr><td>Patient no:- '. $row['No'] . '</td>';
    $diags = explode('-[!$!]-', $row['EMGDiagText']);
    if(!empty($diags)){
        echo '<td><table>';
        foreach($diags as $key => $data){
            echo '<tr><td>Diagnoses ' . ($key+1) . '). ' . $data . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>No Diagnoses</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Hope, it will help and will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by and group_concat

```
SELECT `DK Diagnoses`.`No`,GROUP_CONCAT(`DK Diagnoses`.`EMGDiagText`)
FROM `DK Diagnoses`
JOIN `PATIENTINFO` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `SEXCODE` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Sex` = `SEXCODE`.`SexCode`
JOIN `PROBABILITYCODE` ON `DK Diagnoses`.`Prob` = `PROBABILITYCODE`.`Code`
JOIN `EXAMINFO` ON `PATIENTINFO`.`Exam` = `EXAMINFO`.`Exam`
JOIN `REFTYPE` ON `EXAMINFO`.`RefSource` = `REFTYPE`.`Refsource`
WHERE `DK Diagnoses`.`LabCode` = "Gold" AND  `DK Diagnoses`.`No` = 2598
GROUP BY `DK Diagnoses`.`No`
ORDER BY `DK Diagnoses`.`No` DESC
```

But I would reccomend doing this in PHP, because you are more flexible there. Like showing the diagnoses in a list instead of just comma separated.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way, for me, to do it is like this.

```
SELECT No, GROUP_CONCAT(EMGDiagText) FROM diagnoses GROUP BY No;
```

I hope this helps.